# How to test responsive signing in docusignapi sandbox?

Tags: docusignapi, responsive, sandbox

I would like to test (sandbox) **responsive signing** from the **docusignapi** to provide a mobile-friendly document version to our customers.
Unfortunately, I am being denied to test it since it was not part of my account plan.

I enabled `Allow recipients to view mobile-friendly documents with responsive signing` in the tab `Signing Settings` of the Admin section.
It still did not accept the request. To request responsive signing, I added a DocumentHtmlDefinition to the Document:

`DocumentHtmlDefinition def = new DocumentHtmlDefinition();
def.setDocumentId(documentId);
def.setSource(html);
document.setHtmlDefinition(def);`

"errorCode":"PLAN_ITEM_NOT_ENABLED","message":"A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. This account is not enabled for Smart Sections."
I thought the sandbox allowed the full testing of the api regardless of any account plan. Is it possible that testing responsive signing is not possible with a sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

Mel, This should be enabled in the sandbox account. If you have not created it recently, it's possible this older account doesn't have it yet. Could you try to create a new sandbox account by going to https://developers.docusign.com/ and creating a new one? This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you Inbar. The account is new and our account manager confirmed that responsive signing was activated. Is there anything else that might trigger that error?

Comment: can you send me an email to inbar.gazit@docusign.com with your account information and I'll check it. thanks.